# How can I enable DVD or CD Sharing with the Firewall on?

Tags: security, sharing, optical-drive, firewall

I'm trying to enable "DVD or CD Sharing" in the System Preferences. When I enable it, it says that the Firewall is blocking it. If I go into the Security > Firewall settings, I see that the first item under Advanced... is "DVD or CD Sharing" and that it's set to "Allow incoming connections".

If I disable the Firewall completely, it works correctly. Is there any way to get it to work with the Firewall enabled, though?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your Mac and using the shared media? It seems that the "Blocked by firewall" -message, even though you have it alled in Firewall, is a bug.

Comment: Could you add the tag to show on which version of MacOS X you see this problem?

Comment: Is this problem fully fixed?

Comment: @Senseful Where are you?